# Is it possible to get private variable value using class instance name?

Tags: c++

For example, I've written a class called `Length`:

```
class Length {
public:
    void setValue(float);
private:
    float value_;
};

void
Length::setValue(float newValue) {
    value_ =  newValue;
}
void print(float value) {
    std::cout << value;
}

void computeStuff(float value) {
    //do the computing
}

int main() {

    Length width;
    width.setValue(5);
    std::cout << width; // <-- this is actually just an example
    //what I actually want is:
    print(width); // print 5
    //or perhaps even
    computeStuff(width);

    return 0;
}
```

Now how to make `width` return `value_` or `5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, `width` is not an instance name, it's a name of a variable of type `Length`. You can change your code to retrieve a variable in two ways:

- Add a `friend` operator `<<` for `Length` that does the printing, or
- Add an implicit conversion operator from `Length` to `float`.

The first approach works only for output. You cannot pull the value directly:

```
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Length& len) {
    out << len.value_;
    return out;
}
```

The second approach looks like this:

```
class Length {
    ...
public:
    operator float() const { return value_; }
};
```

Comment: @DleanJeans `const Length&` and `operator float() const` ensure that operators can be applied to `Length` objects even when they are declared `const Length myLength`.

Answer (score 1):

You must overload `operator<<` for your custom type, something like:

```
class Length
{
  ..
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Length& o);
  ..
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Length& o)
{
  os << o.value_;
  return os;
}
```

Mind that this

- must be non member
- is nothing special , just an [operator overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Stream_extraction_and_insertion) applied to a standard way of inserting things into stream of `<iostream>`

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an `operator()` method to print the value 5.

Comment: What's your rationale behind _"overloading << is not recommended."_ ?

Comment: I was suggesting to careful when using in std namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the `<<` operator for your class. You could also use a function to do the operator's work.

**Operator `<<`**

```
#include <iostream>

class Length {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Length& l);
public:
    void setValue(float);
private:
    float value_;
};

void
Length::setValue(float newValue) {
    value_ =  newValue;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Length& l)
{
    os << l.value_;
    return os;
}

int main() {

    Length width;
    width.setValue(5);
    std::cout << width << std::endl; // print 5

    return 0;
}
```

**function:**

```
#include <iostream>

class Length {
    friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream &,const Length &l);
public:
    void setValue(float);
private:
    float value_;
};

void
Length::setValue(float newValue) {
    value_ =  newValue;
}

std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, const Length &l)
{
    os << l.value_;
    return os;
}

int main() {

    Length width;
    width.setValue(5);
    print(std::cout, width) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```