# Convert implicitly float to other type

Tags: c++

For example, I have a class called `Length`.

```
class Length {
public:
    static const float METER_TO_FLOAT_RATIO;

    Length();
    void setValue(float valueInMeter);
    operator const float();

private:
    float valueInMeter_;
};

const float METER_TO_FLOAT_RATIO= 10;

Length::Length() {}

Length::operator const float() {
    return this->valueInMeter_ * METER_TO_FLOAT_RATIO;
}

void drawRectangle(Length width, Length height) {
    //draw width * height rectangle
}

int main() {

    Length width, height;

    width = 20.0f;
    height = 10.0f;

    drawRectangle(width, height);

    return 0;
}
```

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31107327/is-it-possible-to-get-private-variable-value-using-class-instance-name) to figure it out how to convert implicitly from `Length` to `float` but I forgot to or didn't ask about how to convert backward. The method which converts backward will call this statement:

```
    valueInMeter_ = valueInFloat_ / METER_TO_FLOAT_RATIO; //valueInFloat_ is the parameter
```

Comment: `Length &perator=(float f) { valueInMeter_ = f; return *this;}` That?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways that I can think of:

1. Use a converting constructor.

   ```
   Length(float val);
   ```
2. Use an overloaded assignment operator.

   ```
   Length& operator=(float val);
   ```

If you add the converting constructor, you won't need the assignment operator.